# String are missing in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a bug whit my IDE (visual studio 2010 ultimate) and I can't find anything on google.

There are string missing everywhere in the UI for no apparent reasons.

Yesterday it was working fine, but this morning the ui was a mess. I repaired VS, I deinstalled/reinstalled visual studio, I deleted registry keys in attempt to reset them, and nothing works.

http://i1244.photobucket.com/albums/gg580/daves456/vsbug.png

Comment: Do you also experience this problem with other WPF applications? This could be a graphics-related problem

Comment: None that I am aware of. The ones I created works fine.